# How to refresh data-table on click & change the row background color

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I'm trying to change the background color of row on click on button, without page reload. Here is my code, pls let me know what is wrong in my code.
I've try this but i'm not able to do this without page reload. Can anyone help me in this.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "API-Link",
    success: function (data) {
//Some code here

        $('#unmatched-driver tbody').on('click', '.btn_ok', function (e) {
            //location.reload(true);
            var data = oTable.row($(this).parents('tr')).data();
            var tripid = data[1];
            var OKflagid = ($(this).data("value"));
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "API-Link",
                dataType: 'json',
                dataSrc: ''
            });
            $(this).parents('tr').css("background-color", "#bbf6c5");
        });
        $('#unmatched-driver tbody').on('click', '.btn_nok', function (e) {
            //location.reload(true);
            var data = oTable.row($(this).parents('tr')).data();
            var tripid = data[1];
            var NOKflagid = ($(this).data("value"));
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "API-Link",
                dataType: 'json',
                dataSrc: ''
            });
            $(this).parents('tr').css("background-color", '#f6c1bb');
        });
        oTable = $('.trip_unmacthed').DataTable({
            "pageLength": 5,
            "ordering": false,
            "columnDefs": [{
                "targets": [11, 12, 13],
                "visible": false
                            }],
            rowCallback: function (row, data, index) {
                if (data[13] == "1") {
                    $('td', row).css('background-color', '#bbf6c5');
                } else if (data[13] == "2") {
                    $('td', row).css('background-color', '#f6c1bb');
                }
            }

        });
    } 
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to write click event when Document Object Model (DOM) is ready.

[Refer this](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

Just do it.

```
function addClickEvent() {
   $(document).on('click', 'btn_selector', function () {
      $(this).closest('tr').css("background-color", "#bbf6c5");
});

$(function () {
   addClickEvent();
  });
}
```

See, I have done this at my end.

[image]

Follow this step:

(1) routes

```
    Route::group(['prefix' => 'example'], function () {
        Route::get('', 'ExampleController@view');
        Route::get('get_table_data', 'ExampleController@get_table_data');
    });
```

(2) controller

```
    namespace App\Http\Controllers\User;

    use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
    use DataTables;
    use App\Utility;

    class ExampleController extends Controller {

        public function view() {
            return view('pages.store_admin.example-table');
        }

        function get_table_data() {
            return DataTables::eloquent(Utility::query())->toJson();
        }

    }
```

(3) view

```
    @extends('layouts.store_admin')
    @section('title','Example')
    @section('page-title','Example')
    @section('page-title-desc','')
    @section('css')
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs/dt-1.10.15/datatables.min.css"/>
    @endsection

    @section('content')
    <div class="row">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body"> 
                <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12"> 
                    <div class="table-responsive">
                        <table class="table table-ordered" id="example_table" style="width: 100%">
                            <thead style="font-weight: bold;">
                                <tr>
                                    <td>ID</td>
                                    <td>Key</td>
                                    <td>Value</td>
                                    <td>Action</td>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div> 
            </div> 
        </div> 
    </div> 

    @endsection

    @section('js')
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs/dt-1.10.15/datatables.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    <?php
    $data_url = url('example/get_table_data');
    ?>
        window.data_url = '{{ $data_url }}';
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/store_admin/example-table.js') }}"></script>
    @endsection
```

(4) js

```
$(function () {
        addDataTable();
        addClickEvent();
    });

    function addDataTable() {

        window.example_table = $('#example_table').DataTable({
            processing: true,
            serverSide: true,
            targets: 0,
            stateSave: true,
            ajax: {
                url: window.data_url
            },
            columns: [
                {
                    data: 'id',
                    visible: false,
                    orderable: false,
                    searchable: false
                },
                {
                    data: 'key',
                    orderable: true,
                    searchable: true
                },
                {
                    data: 'value',
                    orderable: true,
                    searchable: true
                },
                {
                    data: 'id',
                    name: 'action',
                    orderable: false,
                    searchable: false,
                    render: function (data, type, row) {
                        return '<button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger change-red-color-btn">Red</button>'
                                + ' <button class="btn btn-sm btn-success change-green-color-btn">Green</button>';
                    }
                }
            ]
        });

    }

    function addClickEvent() {

        $(document).on('click', '.change-red-color-btn', function () {
            $(this).closest('tr').css("background-color", "red");
        });

        $(document).on('click', '.change-green-color-btn', function () {
            $(this).closest('tr').css("background-color", "green");
        });
    }
```

Comment: Using only jquery only there is no controller, i cant share the other details. I just want to refresh data-table on click of .btn_ok button & ajax call

Comment: From where your datatable return ?

Comment: sorry din't get you

Comment: Ok, will check, But i want to call api on button click

Comment: You have made some mistake.